# how can i get the calendar selected values?

Tags: php, jquery, html

How can i get calendar selected values in php file? i am using calendar from this link
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiple.html

Answer (score 0):

by `$var = $_POST["formElementName"]`. The date set in the inputfield can be retreived by $_POST, at least, if you use POST as your form-method.

(The selected date gets binded to a DOM-element).

Comment: how can i store the vale in hidden field of selected dates?